# What does "driven" or "driving" mean in terms of electronics?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier

It is a silly question to ask, but I keep seeing statements like "driven by the output signal" or "X drives the load". What does it mean to drive or be driven by X?

Comment: Impose some value. If the net is passive, something active should give it some defined value.

Comment: The output/source drives. The input/load is driven. When something is driving, it is forcing something else to a particular state. When something is being driven, it is being forced to a state by something else.

Answer (score 2):

The engine of your car "drives" the wheels which are "driven". That is, the engine provides the power. The wheels accept or use the power.

In electronics the concept is similar. An amplifier, for example, drives the loudspeaker which is driven. A power-supply drives the motor or the lights.

In general, outputs drive and inputs are driven.

Comment: Don't you think the statement "outputs drive and inputs are driven." conflicts with the analogy that the engine drives the wheels, since the engine is the input power sources, and wheels can be seen as the loads receiving the power?

Comment: No, in my thinking the engine outputs power and, in fact, engines are rated by "output power". Fuel in - power out.